# AVFrame to RGB - decoding artifacts

Tags: image, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, libavformat

I want to programmatically convert a mp4 video file (with h264 codec) to single RGB images. With the command line this looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i test1080.mp4 -r 30 image-%3d.jpg
```

Using this command produces a nice set of pictures. But when I try to programmatically do the same some images (probably B and P frames) look odd (e.g. have kind of distorted areas with difference information etc.). The reading and conversion code is as follow:

```
AVFrame *frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
AVFrame *frameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();

AVPacket packet;

int buffer_size=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, m_codecCtx->width,
    m_codecCtx->height);
uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[buffer_size];

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)frameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
    m_codecCtx->width, m_codecCtx->height);

while (true)
{
    // Read one packet into `packet`
    if (av_read_frame(m_formatCtx, &packet) < 0) {
        break;  // End of stream. Done decoding.
    }

    if (avcodec_decode_video(m_codecCtx, frame, &buffer_size, packet.data, packet.size) < 1) {
        break;  // Error in decoding
    }

    if (!buffer_size) {
        break;
    }

    // Convert
    img_convert((AVPicture *)frameRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, (AVPicture*)frame,
        m_codecCtx->pix_fmt, m_codecCtx->width, m_codecCtx->height);

    // RGB data is now available in frameRGB for further processing
}
```

How can I convert the video stream so that each final image shows all image data, so that information from B and P frames is included in all frames?

**[EDIT:]** A sample image showing the artifacts is here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/201/sampleq.jpg/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If the third argument of `avcodec_decode_video` returns a null value, it does not mean the error. This means that the frame is not yet ready. You need to continue to read frames until the value becomes nonzero.

```
if (!buffer_size) {
    continue;
}
```

**UPD**

Try to add the check and display only the key frames, it will help isolate the problem.

```
while (true)
{
  // Read one packet into `packet`
  if (av_read_frame(m_formatCtx, &packet) < 0) {
    break;  // End of stream. Done decoding.
  }

  if (avcodec_decode_video(m_codecCtx, frame, &buffer_size,
      packet.data, packet.size) < 1)
  {
    break;  // Error in decoding
  }

  if (!buffer_size) {
    continue; // <-- It's important!
  }

  // check for key frame
  if (packet.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY)
  {
    // Convert
    img_convert((AVPicture *)frameRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, (AVPicture*)frame,
      m_codecCtx->pix_fmt, m_codecCtx->width, m_codecCtx->height);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already experimented with this but the result is the same. I checked how the ffmpeg utility does the conversion and this involves many more steps. At the moment I am trying to figure out what exactly is necessary.

Comment: Can you share the example image with artifacts?